# Google GKE Configuration Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I manage multiple projects that use the GKE. I migrated into using secrets however, I cannot get the pods to run now because of a secret/token issue.

It seems when I run `kubectl get secret` I get:

```
default-token-vhn8t      kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      17m
pod-reader-token-q7nh7   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      7m1s
```

However, these are both secrets that belong to another project called `np`. When I run

`gcloud config get-value core/project`

I get `gmbt` which is the correct project.

Do I need to run a compariable `kubectl ???` to set the correct project?

When I run:

`kubectl create secret generic gmbt-server-key --from-file ./keys/server-env/production/.env.json`

It adds the keys to the `np` project and not the `gmbt` project. Maybe a signout/signin might do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

I did a deep dive into

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#config

Here is where I unset the config and then ran

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials "project-cluster" --region="us-central1-c"`

This solved my problem and I think the `gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]` isn't setting the proper values.